# Get connection string used for connecting to SQL using session id

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, dmv

Is there a DMV query to find what connection string used for making connection to SQL server. All i know is the session id.

Is it possible?

I am trying to get alerted proactively for connection pool exhaustion. In my connection string, let's assume i used MAX Pool Size= 5, just wanted to be alerted when 4 connections are used from that pool. I can get this information using sys.dm_exec_sessions table but it will not show if new pool is used.
As new connection pool is created for different connection strings. I need to able to distinguish between connection strings used

Comment: Do you mean @@SPID for the session id, or something else?

Comment: I haven't looked, but keep in mind that connection strings sometimes include passwords. That means making the exact string available as received would be a security issue, and therefore I would be very surprised to find this.

Comment: I have SPID with me, trying to get connection string used for making connection. Or may be a unique id per connection string (no need of actual connection string which will be security issue)